# How can a Object be cast to both List and MyBean

Tags: java

Im writing test cases and im having difficulties understanding how a Object can both be cast to a List.class and MyBean.class. The only way i can see this being possible is through the fact that MyBean.class is Serializable.

```
if (message.getBody(List.class).isEmpty())
            throw new GenericException("array is empty");

MyBean myBean1 = message.getBody(MyBean.class);

if (myBean1.getParam1() != null && !myBean1.getParam1().isEmpty()) {
    //unreachable code here
}
```

If someone could shed some light on this matter i would greatly appriciate it.

Here is some examples of code ive been playing with to try to understand this.

```
    String myBeanJsonFormat= "{" +
            "  \"search\": [" +
            "    {" +
            "      \"operation\": \"equal\"," +
            "      \"path\": \"/core/creator\"," +
            "      \"value\": \"aValue\"," +
            "      \"match\": \"/core/modifiedBy\" " +
            "    }" +
            "  ]" +
            "}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyBean myBeanTest= objectMapper.readValue(myBeanJsonFormat, MyBean.class);
    assert myBeanTest.getParam1() != null; //pass

    List myBeanListTest = (List) myBeanTest; //classCastException below
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: myPackage.MyBean cannot be cast to java.util.List

    byte[] test = SerializationUtils.serialize(myBeanJsonFormat);
    MyBean myBeanTest1 = SerializationUtils.deserialize(test);
    assert myBeanTest1.getSearchOperations()!=null; //ERROR: Exception below
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to mypackage.MyBean
```

Just to be clear my goal is to find out what should i be setting the message body to for this code to funciton correctly.

I can pass a list to get passed the list check but im unable to then pass the MyBean cast.

I can pass a string in a format of a json array, this passes the list cast but not the MyBean cast.

If i comment out the List cast if statement, i can just pass through a MyBean object with no problems.

Comment: MyBean implements List would make that possible.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do exactly, but maybe [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) can help you with it

Comment: What is `message.getBody` ? Is this part of some common library? If this is some sort of deserialization framework, it is very much possible that the same message can be transformed to several alternative Java types.

Comment: `message.getBody(List.class)` and `message.getBody(MyBean.class)` do not look like they return the same object, even for the same `message`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change  `List myBeanListTest = (List) myBeanTest;` instead of this one `List ob = Arrays.asList(myBeanTest);` then your classCastException problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 cases where an object can be cast in 2 other classes.

**Due to interfaces**

Let's be a class that implement the interface List

```
public class myClass extends MyBean implements List {
```

Then an instance of MyClass can be cast to MyBean or to List

**Due to cascading subclass**

If the class MyBean extends a class MySuperBean

```
public class MyBean extends MySuperBean {
```

Then a subclass of MyBean

```
public class MyClass extends MySuperBean {
```

Then an instance of MyClass can be cast either to MyBean or MySuperBean